# How to remove a table row when it's dynamically generated?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, html-table, tablerow

I've been editing someone else's code for a project, and  I stumble every now and then when trying to figure how certain Javascript functions are doing their thing.

Essentially I want to add a remove row button, however it's causing headaches.

So the text for the dynamically generated row is done by this PHP variable:

```
$rowtext .= '<tr>something</tr>';
```

and then the function to generate the row in Javascript:

```
function generateRow(x) {';
            var row_prototype = \'' . $rowtext . '\';
            return row_prototype.replace(/\[index\]/g, x);
            }
```

When the add row button is clicked it performs this action:

```
rowIndex = 1;
function addRow() {
            var nr = generateRow(rowIndex); 
            rowIndex = rowIndex + 1;
            jQuery(\'tbody\').append(nr);';
}
```

I'd presume I'd need to do a similar function to be performed on click, taking into account the rowIndex etc.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Where is this remove a row button, It is much easy if the button is inside the row which you going to remove? If not, which row you want to remove when you hit the button.

Comment: Essentially it's to remove the last row that has been generated by the above code... so remove row rowIndex == 5 or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Essentially it's to remove the last row that has been generated by the above code... so remove row rowIndex == 5 or something

Since you mentioned last row in the comments you can use `:last` selector to get the last row, Try something like below,

```
$('#removeRow').click(function () {
    $('#table_selector tbody tr:last').remove();
});
```

And a button like below somewhere in your markup,

```
<button id="removeRow">Remove a Row</button>
```

**Note:** you need to revise `#table_selector tbody` with specific table ID/Class.

Comment: Thanks for that, I'd tried a similar solution before but just didn't think to 'rowIndex = rowIndex - 1;' when the function was called!

Comment: Would vote up but I don't have enough reputation on stackoverflow

Comment: @DanielDoyle Did it work for you? If yes, you can accept this as an answer. Let me know if you are having any trouble implementing the above.

Comment: Yes it did, I just had to include rowIndex = rowIndex - 1; so when removing the row the addRow function was aware